# Jupyter Kernel dies from nbconvert but not on jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I created a simple kernel which wraps the content of a cell and executes it as SQL in a particular database on jupyter.

The kernel works completely as expected when I open it on a jupyter notebook where it is installed and executes things just fine.

But when I try to execute the notebook using nbconvert, it throws the following error about the kernel being dead before replying.

```
Exception in thread Thread-31:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda/4.2.0/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/opt/anaconda/4.2.0/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "<ipython-input-5-d1a08220a4cf>", line 87, in threadedOperation
    ep.preprocess(nb, {'metadata': {'path': ''}})
  File "/opt/anaconda/4.2.0/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbconvert/preprocessors/execute.py", line 257, in preprocess
    cwd=path)
  File "/opt/anaconda/4.2.0/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbconvert/preprocessors/execute.py", line 241, in start_new_kernel
    kc.wait_for_ready(timeout=startup_timeout)
  File "/opt/anaconda/4.2.0/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/blocking/client.py", line 120, in wait_for_ready
    raise RuntimeError('Kernel died before replying to kernel_info')
RuntimeError: Kernel died before replying to kernel_info
```

Any ideas on what could be causing this or where I can start looking for some answers?

Comment: Every found a solution? Running into a similar issue :)

Comment: Didnt really find a solution but I ended up rewriting the logic of the kernel completely and as a side effect it somehow fixed this issue. Still dont know what caused it though. I believe that certain versions of jupyter and nbconvert also had some issues so updating to the latest version could also be a potential fix.

Comment: Found the same problem using Google Colab in 2020. Did someone found a solution?

Answer (score 2):

found the solution

```sh
python3 -m ipykernel install --user
```

https://github.com/udacity/aind2-dl/issues/9

Answer (score 1):

After searching for hours, it solved the problem for me by simply reinstall ipykernel:

```
pip uninstall ipykernel
pip install ipykernel
```